# React Meteor: findOne() doesn't work as a condition in if

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm stuck in a problem with data flow. I'm using Meteor and React.

What I wanna do is like this:

If there is a record having the same "country" and "question_id", not create anything but just increment "yes/no" value. Otherwise, create a new record and increment "yes/no"value.

However it ends up to creating a new record every time no matter if the record already exists. I checked "country" and "question_id" are defined. This is not supposed to create a record having the same country and question_id, is it? I guess some lines are executed before the data is ready..... How can I make the code going step by step? Or does it have other problems? I would really appreciate if you give me any clue. Thank you.

```
  handleAlternate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.dataInsert(false);  
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.dataInsert(true);
  }

  dataInsert(yesflag){
    const country = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    if(Answers.findOne({country: country, question_id: id}) == null){//Why is this always true?
      Answers.insert({
        country,
        question_id: id,
        yes: 0,
        no: 0,
        createdAt: new Date(), 
      });
    }
    const doc = Answers.findOne({country: country, question_id: id});
    console.log(Answers.findOne({country: country, question_id: id}));
    if(yesflag == true){
      Answers.update({_id: doc._id}, 
        { $inc: {yes: 1}});
    }else{
      Answers.update({_id: doc._id}, 
        { $inc: {no: 1}});
    }

    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = '';
  }
```

Comment: Can you do a console.log(Answers.findOne({country: country, question_id: id})) after the line "const id = ..." and tell me what it prints?

Comment: @JohnSmith 
It prints "undefined". But when I input findOne() in shell with country and id which are defined in this code(I checked with console.log), it returns the right record...

Comment: I don't doubt that the record exists in the database. It is more likely that you haven't done your publication / subscription correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.findOne()` Finds the first document that matches the selector, as ordered by sort and skip options. Returns `undefined` if no matching document is found.

So you must just do as below

```
let answer = Answers.findOne({country: country, question_id: id};
if(!answer){}
```

or

```
let totalAnswers = Answers.find({country: country, question_id: id}).count();
if(totalAnswers == 0) {}
```

> for detailed documentation [CLICK HERE](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne)